# Find doc by relative array element positions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to search a field in array and want to know what is the index of that field in array is it possible to find it?
example:

```
doc1: {id:123, hobby:['chess','cards','dance']}
doc2: {id:123, hobby:['cards','dance','chess']}
```

I want to search only the document which has 
`chess` and `cards` but only the one which has `chess` before `card`. So in case `doc1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator, coupling it with the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) operator to keep it reasonably performant:

```js
db.test.find({
  // Find all the docs where hobby contains both 'cards' and 'chess'
  hobby: {$all: ['cards', 'chess']},
  // Of those, run this $where query that evaluates the indexes of the matched elements
  $where: "this.hobby.indexOf('cards') > this.hobby.indexOf('chess')"
})
```

Add an index on `hobby` for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

For the best performance you would actually use [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage for a "query" to narrow down possible matches to documents that contain [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) the elements in the array, and [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to filter from the remaining results:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "hobby": { "$all": [ "chess", "cards" ] } } },
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$eq": [
          { "$filter": {
              "input": "$hobby",
              "as": "hobby",
              "cond": {
                "$or": [
                  { "$eq": [ "$$hobby", "chess" ] },
                  { "$eq": [ "$$hobby", "cards" ] }
                ]
              }
          }},
          ["chess","cards"]
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }     
  }}
])
```

The reason that works is because [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) can return only the elements that match the conditions given here, and returns them *"in the same order"* in which they are stored in the original document.

Once "filtered" down, the array should then be an **exact match** for the content `["chess","cards"]` if indeed those elements in the original array were in that order.

Note that while it may "look" simpler, you cannot use ["set operators"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/) to test this since "sets" are not actually considered to be ordered.

So you need something that maintains the order, and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is really the only thing that can do this with array content in an efficient way. So the solution is indeed restricted to requiring a MongoDB 3.2 or greater release in order to actually work.

For older releases, see the [answer from  JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458564/2313887) using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to apply an `.indexOf()` test on the array elements as the additional filter to using [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/).

But if you have MongoDB 3.2 with the available operators, then the native coded operations available to the aggregation framework run much faster than the JavaScript evaluation of[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), and should be used in preference.